# Handle access dashboard with laravel and entrust

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, acl, entrust

I tried using [entrust package](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) and works well.
I have different types of roles assign to different users.
The users are have roles access to dashboard to do according to their permission.
I need to make middleware on routes using [entrust package](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) to check user has last one role and permission before access the dashboard.
or if there other best performance/solution to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Entrust has its own middleware,

```
'role' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
'permission' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
'ability' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class,
```

You just need to register them in `App\Http\Kernel.php`.
In your `routes\web.php` create a group with a middleware for specific users:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=> 'role'], function({
   Route::get('/somelink', 'SomeController@somefunction');
});
```

Comment: The issuse is
I need to provide 1 parameter exactly as in the docs:
->middleware('role:editor')